# What does the operator |= mean in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I could see this operator |= used in some sample code in my project. The exact code is given below

```
DocumentRetrievalOptions docRetrievalOptions = DocumentRetrievalOptions.ByTargetJurisdiction;    
    docRetrievalOptions |= DocumentRetrievalOptions.ByUniqueId;
```

Where 'DocumentRetrievalOptions' is of type enum.

It would be of great help, if some one lets me know, what really does this mean.

Answer (score 6):

It is a [Bitwise/Logical OR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) - assign operator. `A |= B;` is the same as `A = A | B;`

Since `DocumentRetrievalOptions` is an `enum`, in your case `|=` performs a bitwise operation.

Answer (score 1):

It is a shortcut for:

```
docRetrievalOptions = docRetrievalOptions | DocumentRetrievalOptions.ByUniqueId;
```

`|` being the bitwise-OR operator. In this way it works similarly to `+=`, `-=` and other operators in this style.

Answer (score 1):

Usually values in an enumeration are used as flags, the |= or "or equals" operator simply takes the bit representation of these values and does a bitwise OR on them. This way you "enable" another feature or flag of the enumeration (in this case the retrieval options for a document os its either by target jursisdiction OR unique id).

Answer (score 1):

Also read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx
It's really usefull if you wish to use this operator in this way.

Answer (score 0):

It applies the * bitwise or* operator (`|`) to both operands and stores the result inside `docRetrievalOptions`.

It is the same as `docRetrievalOptions = docRetievalOptions | DocumentRetrievalOptions.ByUniqueId;`

It interprets the enumeration as an int and then does the operation.